# Reinmann Sum of Integral for $P = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{r}{n^2+r^2}$

Tags: calculus

If $\displaystyle P = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{r}{n^2+r^2}$ and $\displaystyle Q = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{r}{n^2+r^2}$, Then Which one is Greater.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using Reinmann Sum of Integral::

Given $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{r}{n^2+r^2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{r}{n}}{1+\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2}$

Now Let $\displaystyle \frac{r}{n} = x,$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} = dx,$ and changing Limits, We get

So our Sum is convert into $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$

So $P$ and $Q$ are equal, But answer given as $P\neq Q$

can anyone explain it to me,

Is possible then plz explain me using Diagram

Thanks

Comment: The name is Riemann, not Reinmann.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P-Q=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n^2+n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n}$$

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee. Got it.Would you like to explain me how can i get $\displaystyle P>\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$ and $\displaystyle Q <\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$, Thanks